# Real values of the derivative of a Dirichlet series function

Tags: complex-analysis

Let us consider the L-series given by:

$f(s)=∑_{n=1}^{∞}a_{n}/n^{s}$

where $a_{n}$ are the coefficients of Dirichlet series of the Hasse--Weil L-function of a modular curve $C$ over $ℚ$. This series is entire function and have a holomorphic continuation. I know that if $s$ is real then $f(s)$ is also real as can be seen from the convergent series.

My **question** is: Is the same thing holds true for the derivative of $f$ with respect to $s$, i.e., if $s$ is real then $f'(s)$ is also real.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, if $f: \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ is holomorphic and maps reals to reals, then the same is true for $f'(s)$, just by the definition of the derivative:
$$f'(s) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(s+h)-f(s)}{h}.$$
If $h$ tends to $0$ on the real line, then the above quotient is real and tends to $f'(s)$, hence the limit $f'(s)$ is also real.

Alternatively, suppose $f$ is given by a power series $f(s) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n s^n$. Then also $g(s) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \overline{b_n} s^n$ is entire. It coincides with $f$ on the real line, hence everywhere by the identity theorem. So $b_n = \overline{b_n}$ for all $n$, i.e. the $b_n$ are real. Conversely, if all coefficients $b_n$ are real then $f$ maps reals to reals.

Therefore, we have shown: An entire function $f(s) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n s^n$ maps reals to reals iff all $b_n \in \mathbb R$. This property is certainly preserved under differentiation.